# fs overwrites file on Jenkins instead of appending

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a small NodeJs app that performs some actions and in the end, it appends the result to a textfile. The script works locally but when I run it on Jenkins, the file gets overwritten instead of appended. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

```
 fs.appendFile('timing.txt', new Date().toISOString() + ' ' + timing + '\n', 
 function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong when writing to the file');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's unlikely that `appendFile` would be broken when executed in a Jenkins job. It's more likely that the file does not exist in the Jenkins environment, in which case `appendFile` would create a new file.  Does your Jenkins job do something like destroying the workspace before running? If there's no obvious reason for the file to not exist then you could instrument your Node script to report whether the fie exists before you try to `appendFile` to it. Also, if you're really unlucky it's possible that the `Date()` might change while the job is running.

Comment: I am certain that the workspace does not get cleared since I modded the code to add a timestamp to the filename. After a couple of builds, multiple files were present with a different timestmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Timing.txt was checked in into Git.
After each run, timing.txt got modified by my code.
On the next run, Git would detect that timing.txt in my workspace was not the same version as the one in Git and therefore, it would check it out again, thus 'overwriting' my results from the previous runs.